# How to hide a specific child from an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In an ExpandableListView, is there a way to hide a specific child from the EXpandableListView, for example , hide Child21 ...?

But i want that this be present , i dont want delete this from the List ,i want handle a specific child with a specific behavior and hide an specific children and this dont change from her position in the childList.

Or its possible dont draw the layout in the specific position?...

[image: ExpandableListViewSaple]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call `removeAllViews()` on the top element of the child layout resource that you pass to the list adapter.